# CSS transform translateX to stay in position and become a default image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I made a little animation where the ground starts to move on a <kbd>Enter</kbd> key click and stops at a <kbd>Enter</kbd> key click, but every time it stops it pops back into original position. Can I make the animation stop at a certain point and remain there and even better set the position as a default one?

Here is the code:

**CSS:**

```css
.surface {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300vw;
  background: url("floor.png");
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-1080px);
  }
}

.moveRight {
  animation: moveRight 10s linear infinite;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $surface = $('.surface');

  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $($surface).toggleClass('moveRight');
      
      if (frog.getAttribute("src") == "FrogIdle.gif") {
        frog.setAttribute("src", "forgjump.gif");
      } 
      else {
        frog.setAttribute("src", "FrogIdle.gif");
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Since you are using `.toggleClass()` the class is added and removed; hence the class is applied and unapplied when this happens. I would suggest using `.animate()` instead so you can make use of the step callback and stop the animation on an event.